Question about democracy and regime - Przeworski et al
In Przeworski et al.'s Democracy and Development: Political Institutions and Well-Being in the World, 1950-1990 (page 18-19), the authors stated:

... by "regime" we mean the system of relations between the civil society and the state. A regime is a system of rules and practices that determine who has political rights, how they can be exercised, and with what effects for the control over the state. Hence, even if dictators succeed one another, the regime, in our sense of the term, remains the same as long as it remains a dictatorship. Thus, when General Viola overthrows General Videla, we consider the entire period as one dictatorship, rather than as "Videla" and "Viola" regimes. And even in those rare cases when the basic democratic institutions are transformed without a break in legality, as in France in 1958, we still consider each of them as a single "democratic regime."

I am confused by the part highlighted with bold and italic. Do the authors mean, in the case of France in 1958, "France before 1958" and "France after 1958" are considered two democratic regimes, or "France before 1958" and "France after 1958" are considered as one democratic regime (even though the basic democratic institutions are transformed without a break in legality)?
By "... consider each of them as a single 'democratic regime'", I think the book means the latter; that is, "France before 1958" is a democratic regime and "France after 1958" is another democratic regime. But why? If in the case of "Videla/Viola dictatorship" the whole period stall be regarded as one single dictatorship regime, then why would the France case be considered as two different democratic regimes?
I lack the historical and political background knowledge about France in that period. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain it to me!

The authors mean that "France before 1958" and "France after 1958" are considered two democratic regimes.
This corresponds to the very widely adopted classification scheme for the regimes in French history, which is as follows (all dates are years CE):

The Carolingian Empire (800-843) (formally merging the Frankish and Lombard Kingdoms)
The Western Frankish realm of the Carolingian Empire (once it was ceded to Charles the Bald in the Treaty of Verdun) (843-987)
The Ancien Régime of the Kingdom of France (987-1789) (established when Hugh Capet was elected king)
The Constitutional Monarchy (1789-1792) (as a result of the French Revolution)
The First Republic (1792–1804)
The First Empire (1804-1814)
The Bourbon Restoration (1814-1830)
The July Monarchy (1830-1848)
The Second Republic (1848–1852)
The Second Empire (1852-1870)
The Third Republic (1870–1940)
The Vichy France Regime (1940-1944) (a Nazi puppet government)
The Provisional Government of the French Republic (1944-1946)
The Fourth Republic (1946–1958)
The Fifth Republic (1958–present).

The circumstances involved in the break between the Fourth Republic and the Fifth Republic in France are explained by the Smithsonian magazine as follows:

The Fifth Republic is the name of France’s current government. It
began in 1958, after a coup at the hands of the French military in
colonial Algeria convinced officials in Paris to dissolve Parliament.
Fearing that the military could extend their control beyond Africa,
the government called former general Charles de Gaulle out of
retirement to hold the country together, as he did during the
post-liberation years of World War II. To do so, he crafted a new
constitution. Under this government, the president has substantial
power, holds a term of five years (it was originally seven) and,
following a change to the constitution in 1962, is directly elected by
the French people. (de Gaulle held the position until 1968.)
This system of government differs dramatically from previous
republics, which relied on parliamentary rule. In the Fifth Republic,
the head-of-state appoints a prime minister to lead the Parliament
(which is comprised of a Senate and a National Assembly), controls the
armed forces and France’s nuclear arsenal, can dissolve Parliament,
and can hold referendums on laws or constitutional changes.
One caveat to the president’s powers is the possibility of
“cohabitation,” when the president is from a different political party
than the majority of politicians in the parliament. In these cases,
the president must choose a prime minister who will be accepted by the
parliament, and the two share powers of governing more equitably.

The article continues by explaining the various other Republics in French history.
A comparable transition of regimes in U.S. history was between government under the Articles of Confederation (1777-1789) (which formalized the structure of the post-Declaration of Independence government of the United States that commenced on July 4, 1776), and government under the current U.S. Constitution (1789-present).

The paragraph is definitely confusing, since it starts by talking about a situation where it's not a regime change, then the final sentence abruply switches gears and the example is a regime change, but doesn't really explain the difference.

I think your analysis is correct but your interpretation is not.  "Each of them" refers to each country in which this occurs, and not to the "each of France before and France after 1958".  The intent is that France should be considered to be a single democratic regime before and after 1958, despite the establishment of the fifth republic
